# Workaround for tar 1.27's bug in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, tar, yocto

Ubuntu 14.04 latest tar version is 1.27.1:

```
tar --version
tar (GNU tar) 1.27.1
```

But compiling Yocto (as provided by Altera:   http://download.altera.com/akdlm/software/acdsinst/13.0/156/ib_installers/linux-socfpga-13.02-RC10-src.bsx, and instructions given here:   http://rocketboards.org/foswiki/view/Documentation/AlteraSoCDevelopmentBoardYoctoGettingStarted) have been giving this error:

```
| tar: --same-order option cannot be used with -c
| Try 'tar --help' or 'tar --usage' for more information.
```

Attributed to 1.27's tar feature (http://lists.openembedded.org/pipermail/openembedded-core/2013-October/085105.html).   Alternatively I download tar 1.26 from GNU website and compilation gives the following error:

```
  CC     argp-eexst.o
In file included from argp.h:24:0,
                 from argp-eexst.c:27:
./stdio.h:479:1: error: ‘gets’ undeclared here (not in a function)
 _GL_WARN_ON_USE (gets, "gets is a security hole - use fgets instead");
 ^
```

So does anyone have any workaround when compiling Yocto in the latest patched Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: Another example:
https://lists.yoctoproject.org/pipermail/yocto/2013-October/016540.html

Comment: what are you asking? You haven't asked any question? Besides, you lack a lot of info. What version are you using? In the currently supported versions, this should have been patched. If the fixes are missing in one of the supported releases, that's something that needs to be fixed.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that was explicit enough - all the links I quoted does not have any answers, and mine is just another one more of those questions.

Comment: Well, you omitted the question in the original question...
Though, you still haven't given us any information on what version of Yocto etc you're using. That's crucial to know.

Comment: thanks for your comment, i have added more info.   for your help, i have +1 your comment.

Comment: Well, I guess that as you've got you workaround, the question is to be considered answered. Though, next time, please, try to identify what version of Yocto Project / Poky / Bitbake is being used. Things might have changed depending on which version you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got overcome the problem.   It is not a bug with tar 1.27.1, just that it breaks many existing system that uses the old tar feature.

I took 1.26 version of tar from GNU, commented out the comment in line 479 in stdio.h that created the error, and generated a new tar that ignore the gets() warning.   Not a long term solution, but now at least I can successfully compile Yocto.

Comment: Yes, not a solution but a temporary workaround. What yocto version are you using? Like I stated above, the supported versions ought to be fixed since a long time. If you need to use an older version, it should be relatively easy to cherry-pick (and fix the merge conflicts) the couple of patches needed to make it work using a new tar version.

Comment: not really, the entire Yocto came as a special download from vendor himself:  http://rocketboards.org/foswiki/view/Documentation/AlteraSoCDevelopmentBoardYoctoGettingStarted 
and it is wiser to patch tar then to patch the Yocto itself, which is a lot more complicated and may have other dependencies.

Comment: Each to his own... I don't necessarily share that opinion, but as long as it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this can be technically considered a bug or not but for sure it is also present on version 1.29 and that silently broke my amanda-zdm backups. 
Not funny. 
For me the solution was to downgrade to version 1.26